# WSO2 APIM - Restoring the Default APIs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Over the last few month, I have been using the WSO2 governance registry and API manager products as a service registry for my organization. In a recent test of upgrading to APIM 1.8, my team accidently removed the default APIs (WADL, Resource, WSDL, Discovery, etc.). I believe there used to be a way to add this back but I no longer can figure out how. Can someone help point me in the right direction? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When restarting the governance registry, it will add the default APIs if they are not available in the APIM database.